Why is Cholesky decomposition not a copula?
I've been told that Cholesky decomposition can be used as part of a process involving copulas to generate correlated random variables, but it is not a copula itself. From my understanding, both of these can be used to simulate dependent random variables. So why the distinction, what's the difference? Please help me understand.

Cholesky decomposition is used in Monte Carlo methods to easily simulate correlated random variables, where the correlation is well defined/easily defined. Like multivariate distribution normal.
In some cases, you  can have two random variables with complex correlational structure, which can not be modeled directly by a multivariate distribution. In that case you will use a copula. They allow you to describe complex correlation structure by a simple multivariate distribution and two marginal distributions.
In nutshell:

Cholesky decomposition is a method used in Monte Carlo simulations to sample from multivariate distribution.
Copula is a model to model complex correlations between random variables. When you sample from copula, you can use Cholesky decomposition.

For more information on copulas, I recommend:

An intuitive, visual guide to copulas
Bayesian copula estimation: Describing correlated joint distributions


You could say: Copula is much more general, applying to just about any multivariate distribution. Cholesky is a clever trick to generate a multivariate Gaussian by taking advantage of the linearity properties of (single variable) Gaussian. In some sense all Gaussians are alike and can mimick each other via linear transformations,  this does not generalize to other distribs

@nbbo2 Great point!
